# (stress) testing tool for ASP.net/C#

Tags: automated-testing, performance, c#, web-application, stress-testing

I am a Software QA for 3 years, however, I only experienced manual testing which I act the role as end-user in the application (front-end and back-office), I am now hired in other company which I am only the SQA, this is the first time there hire a SQA.

I noticed that there's an error in their web application which cannot replicated by manual testing. I'm sure that automation testing will be the solution to do stress testing in the website, however, I have no idea regarding automation testing, I need your help

Can anyone suggest a (stress) testing tool for ASP.net/C#? and how will I use the tool?

Answer (score 2):

You can choose any of the tools listed i.e. [here](http://www.opensourcetesting.org/category/testing-tools-overview/performance/?menu-page=overview). When it comes to web applications load testing it doesn't matter which tool you will choose, web applications normally return HTML pages therefore underlying technology doesn't matter.

The above list can be short-listed to the following free and open source load testing tools:

- [Grinder](http://grinder.sourceforge.net/)
- [Gatling](http://gatling.io/)
- [Apache JMeter](http://jmeter.apache.org/)
- [Tsung](http://tsung.erlang-projects.org/)

Check out [Open Source Load Testing Tools: Which One Should You Use?](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/open-source-load-testing-tools-which-one-should-you-use) article to learn about main features, sample scripts and reports and see the comparison.

Answer (score 1):

Your question is a bit broad, but I will try to give you some hints and direction.

There are some performance and load testing tools to automate stress testing of a website.

- Microsoft included [performance testing in their Visual Studio](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/test/performance-testing/getting-started/getting-started-with-performance-testing).
- [jMeter](http://jmeter.apache.org/), the open source facto standard, but uses Java (In a MS-only shop maybe stick with MS products).

How you use them:

- Read some tutorials, like getting started
- Experiment a bit
- Read the documentation
- Experiment a bit
- Ask non-broad, clear and specific questions on [SQA.SE](https://sqa.stackexchange.com/)
- Experiment a bit
- Working proof of concept

Before you know you are an expert :)